# AWS IAM policy JSON with time limit and time zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to add IAM policy with time limit. But in the time limit it didn't have way to specify the time zone. How can define the time zone or what is the time zone considered here?

```
{
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*",
         "Condition": {
            "DateGreaterThan" : {
               "aws:CurrentTime" : "2019-01-17T01:00:00Z"
             }
          }
      }
```

Comment: please take a look on this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084168/time-frame-based-iam-user-restriction

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all dates and times in AWS are in **UTC Timezone**.

That’s quite annoying for us in those parts of the world that switch from *standard* to *daylight saving* (DST) time and back every half a year as the offset from UTC changes.

You can try to specify a timezone in your timestamp as `2019-01-17T01:00:00+12:00` which may or may not work but it won’t help with the DST changing offset.